# Restful RequestFilter making optional

Tags: java, web-services, resteasy

Here is my scenario.
I have rest method which is called in two case

1. It doesn't need authentication hence session token is not needed
2. It needs authentication and get user object from session token

How to satisfy both condition in one method? Or should I keep it without `authentication(removing @RequestFilter)` and use session token just for getting user object and not for authentication purpose?

or should I just make two method which are ideally same?

EDIT : I am getting session token from header

Answer (score 0):

If you use that parameter as RequestParam then you can set it optional like below method signature ..

@RequestMapping(value = "/someurl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String doAuthentication(@RequestParam(value = "authToken", required = false) String authToken) {}

Comment: No. session token is coming in header